# Replace multiple OR operators with a single IN or ANY operator

Tags: sql, oracle, any

I would like to query a list of cities that end in vowels and I would like each city in the list to be distinct. The code noted below works fine but I would like to achieve the same thing using the IN or ANY operators.I have attached a picture of the description of the table I'm working with. Thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Station
WHERE City LIKE '%a' 
OR City LIKE '%e'
OR City LIKE '%i'
OR City LIKE '%o'
OR City LIKE '%u';
```

[Table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyevp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp

```
select DISTINCT 
City   FROM Station 
WHERE  regexp_like(city,'[aeiou]$')
```

Comment: This does not work for the cases in which end vowels are upper-case @ToluwalopeB

Comment: Think the systematic is clear ... if an addtional character is necessary it can be added

Comment: all the cities names are lower case so this works for my purposes. I understand that I can tweak it for upper case if needed. @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>[`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)</kbd>

```
SELECT distinct CITY
  FROM station
 WHERE regexp_like(CITY, '[aeiou]$', 'i');
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d212fe7a635e7bf2eb86252691b1159b)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could use Oracle's `REGEXP_LIKE` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM Station
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(City, '^.*[aeiou]$', 'i');
```

The regex pattern `^.*[aeiou]$` will match any city name which ends in a vowel.  The third `i` parameter passed to `REGEXP_LIKE` tells Oracle to do the match in case insensitive mode, in case that would matter.

Comment: Could you please explain the need for " ^.* " in the regex pattern? The code works fine with or without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `in`, you can:

```
where substr(city, -1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

You can use `lower()` if you need to handle upper-case as well.